# Issues with linking GLFW to the executable with CMake

Tags: cmake

I am currently trying to link the GLFW library with my executable files in CLion. After hours of research and trial & error, I am stuck. I am using `find_package()` to locate my GLFW library. For some reason my FindGLFW.cmake file seems to correctly locate the library in `/usr/local/lib/libglfw.a` when using find_library(), but my CMakeLists.txt returns empty with find_package(). I don't really understand how that's possible. Could someone help me out?

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(learnopengl)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/CMake)

find_package(glfw 3.3 REQUIRED)
message(STATUS "(CMakeLists.txt) GLFW: [${glfw}]")
if (NOT glfw)
    message(SEND_ERROR "(CMakeLists) Did not find glfw_library")
endif()


add_executable(learnopengl src/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(learnopengl glfw)
```

FindGLFW.cmake

```
    find_library( GLFW_LIBRARY
            NAMES
                glfw3 glfw
            PATHS
                ${GLFW_LOCATION}/lib
                $ENV{GLFW_LOCATION}/lib
                /usr/lib64
                /usr/lib
                /usr/local/lib64
                /usr/local/lib
                NO_DEFAULT_PATH
                DOC "The GLFW library"
            )

 message(STATUS "(FindGLFW.cmake) GLFW_INCLUDE_DIR: [${GLFW_INCLUDE_DIR}]")
 message(STATUS "(FindGLFW.cmake) GLFW_LIB: [${GLFW_LIBRARY}]")

 if (NOT GLFW_LIBRARY)
     message(SEND_ERROR "(FindGLFW.cmake) Did not find glfw_library")
```

Output when running `cmake ..`

```sh
-- (FindGLFW.cmake) GLFW_INCLUDE_DIR: [/usr/local/include]
-- (FindGLFW.cmake) GLFW_LIB: [/usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a]
-- (CMakeLists.txt) GLFW: []
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:12 (message):
  (CMakeLists) Did not find glfw_library
```

When I tried to directly include find_library() in my `CMakeLists.txt` instead, it did locate the library, but when I tried to link it with my executable, I got a linker error saying it couldn't locate the library:

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(learnopengl)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/CMake)

find_library( GLFW_LIBRARY
            NAMES
                glfw3 glfw
            PATHS
                ${GLFW_LOCATION}/lib
                $ENV{GLFW_LOCATION}/lib
                /usr/lib64
                /usr/lib
                /usr/local/lib64
                /usr/local/lib
                NO_DEFAULT_PATH
                DOC "The GLFW library"
            )

 message(STATUS "(FindGLFW.cmake) GLFW_LIB: [${GLFW_LIBRARY}]")

 if (NOT GLFW_LIBRARY)
     message(SEND_ERROR "(CMakeLists.txt) Did not find glfw_library")
 endif()

add_executable(learnopengl src/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(learnopengl GLFW_LIBRARY)
```

Output:

```sh
 ~/dev/projects/opengl/learnopengl/build  cmake ..                                                                                                       
-- (CMakeLists.txt) GLFW_LIB: [/usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a]
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/Philipp/dev/projects/opengl/learnopengl/build
 ~/dev/projects/opengl/learnopengl/build  cmake --build .                                                                                                  
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable learnopengl
ld: library not found for -lGLFW_LIBRARY
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [learnopengl] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/learnopengl.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I would really appreciate some hints as to what I am doing wrong. I can't see why it wouldn't locate/link the library correctly.

Thank you!

Comment: After your `FindGLFW.cmake` script it executed, expression `${GLFW_LIBRARY}` contains the path to the library. Just use this expression in `target_link_libraries` call. Why do you check `glfw` and try to link with `GLFW_LIBRARY` as a *plain* library name?

Answer (score 0):

In cmake, arguments are case sensitive, so find_package should be

```
find_package(GLFW 3.3 REQUIRED)
```

Linker problem can be found easily in the logs. You are trying to link -lGLFW_LIBRARY, however what you want to link is GLFW_LIBRARY's value, /usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a .

```
target_link_libraries(learnopengl ${GLFW_LIBRARY})
```